# Are the upgrades in Search Layout upgradable

Tags: managed-package, salesforce1-app, search-layout

Are the changes madeup in Default search layout upgradable?
I checked the ISV salesforce guide, but was not able to get the idea.

I had managed package and we added more fields to search layout for the managed package.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include more details.

Comment: Are you talking about a managed package that you have built?  Please [edit] your post to include all the relevant details.

Comment: Hi David, certainly I have updated the post. You are right, its about managed package.

Answer (score 0):

Search Layouts are [documented to be editable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm#mdc_custom_objects) by both subscribers and developers. That means that your changes will not push to existing subscribers, but will be received by new subscribers.